# How to secure all newly created graphs in Apache Fuseki with SecurityEvaluator?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, fuseki

It is possible to assign SecurityEvaluator to all newly created graphs?
I can create a secured model it works OK, but I'd like to apply security to all newly created graphs. The user can create a new graph with just INSERT query and then SecurityEvaluator is not applied to that graph.

**UPDATE**
For TDB dataset I have written a wrapper that implements DatasetGraph and proxies requests to wrapped DatasetGraph if it's allowed. Is this enough to be sure the whole dataset is protected (Assuming SecurityEvaluator implemented correctly of course)? I mean if there can be any other way to access/modify the dataset bypassing this SecuredDatasetGraph?

Code of SecuredDatasetGraph

```
package com.vdanyliuk.jena.security;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.Iter;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Graph;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Node;
import org.apache.jena.graph.NodeFactory;
import org.apache.jena.permissions.SecurityEvaluator;
import org.apache.jena.query.ReadWrite;
import org.apache.jena.query.TxnType;
import org.apache.jena.shared.AccessDeniedException;
import org.apache.jena.shared.Lock;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetGraph;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.core.Quad;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.graph.GraphZero;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.util.Context;

public class SecuredDatasetGraph implements DatasetGraph {

    public static final String DEFAULT_GRAPH_SECURITY_NAME = "TEST";
    private DatasetGraph base;
    private SecurityEvaluator securityEvaluator;

    protected SecuredDatasetGraph(DatasetGraph base, SecurityEvaluator securityEvaluator) {
        this.base = base;
        this.securityEvaluator = securityEvaluator;
    }

    private boolean hasReadAccess(Node test) {
        return securityEvaluator.evaluate(securityEvaluator.getPrincipal(), SecurityEvaluator.Action.Read, test);
    }

    private boolean hasCreateAccess(Node test) {
        return securityEvaluator.evaluate(securityEvaluator.getPrincipal(), SecurityEvaluator.Action.Create, test);
    }

    private boolean hasDeleteAccess(Node test) {
        return securityEvaluator.evaluate(securityEvaluator.getPrincipal(), SecurityEvaluator.Action.Delete, test);
    }

    @Override
    public Graph getDefaultGraph() {
        boolean isReadAllowed = hasReadAccess(NodeFactory.createURI(DEFAULT_GRAPH_SECURITY_NAME));
        if (isReadAllowed) {
            return base.getDefaultGraph();
        } else {
            return GraphZero.instance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Graph getGraph(Node graphNode) {
        boolean isReadAllowed = hasReadAccess(graphNode);
        if (isReadAllowed) {
            return base.getGraph(graphNode);
        } else {
            return GraphZero.instance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Graph getUnionGraph() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Union graph is not supported by secured dataset.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsGraph(Node graphNode) {
        return hasReadAccess(graphNode);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDefaultGraph(Graph g) {
        base.setDefaultGraph(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void addGraph(Node graphName, Graph graph) {
        if (hasCreateAccess(graphName)) {
            base.addGraph(graphName, graph);
        } else {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("User is not allowed to create graph " + graphName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeGraph(Node graphName) {
        if (hasDeleteAccess(graphName)) {
            base.removeGraph(graphName);
        } else {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("User is not allowed to delete graph " + graphName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Node> listGraphNodes() {
        List<Node> result = getBaseGraphNodes();
        return getReadAllowedGraphNodes(result)
                .iterator();
    }

    private List<Node> getReadAllowedGraphNodes(List<Node> result) {
        return result.stream()
                .filter(this::hasReadAccess)
                .collect(toList());
    }

    private List<Node> getBaseGraphNodes() {
        List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
        base.listGraphNodes().forEachRemaining(result::add);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Quad quad) {
        Node graph = quad.getGraph();
        if (hasCreateAccess(graph)) {
            base.add(quad);
        } else {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("User is not allowed to add triples to graph " + graph);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Quad quad) {
        Node graph = quad.getGraph();
        if (hasDeleteAccess(graph)) {
            base.delete(quad);
        } else {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("User is not allowed to delete triples from graph " + graph);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Node g, Node s, Node p, Node o) {
        if (hasCreateAccess(g)) {
            base.add(g, s, p, o);
        } else {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("User is not allowed to add triples to graph " + g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Node g, Node s, Node p, Node o) {
        if (hasDeleteAccess(g)) {
            base.delete(g, s, p, o);
        } else {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("User is not allowed to delete triples from graph " + g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAny(Node g, Node s, Node p, Node o) {
        if (g == null || Quad.isDefaultGraph(g)) { //default graph case
            if (hasDeleteAccess(NodeFactory.createURI(DEFAULT_GRAPH_SECURITY_NAME))) {
                base.deleteAny(g, s, p, o);
                return;
            }
        } else if (g.equals(Node.ANY)) {
            if (getBaseGraphNodes().stream().allMatch(this::hasDeleteAccess)) {
                base.deleteAny(g, s, p, o);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            if (hasDeleteAccess(g)) {
                base.deleteAny(g, s, p, o);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new AccessDeniedException("User is not allowed to delete triples from graph " + g);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Quad> find() {
        return Iter.filter(base.find(), quad -> hasReadAccess(quad.getGraph()));
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Quad> find(Quad quad) {
        return find(quad.getGraph(), quad.getSubject(), quad.getPredicate(), quad.getObject());
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Quad> find(Node g, Node s, Node p, Node o) {
        if (g == null || Quad.isDefaultGraph(g)) { //default graph case
            if (hasReadAccess(NodeFactory.createURI(DEFAULT_GRAPH_SECURITY_NAME))) {
                return base.find(g, s, p, o);
            }
        } else if (g.equals(Node.ANY)) {
            return Iter.filter(base.find(g, s, p, o), q -> hasReadAccess(q.getGraph()));
        } else {
            if (hasReadAccess(g)) {
                return base.find(g, s, p, o);
            }
        }
        throw new AccessDeniedException("User is not allowed to delete triples from graph " + g);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Quad> findNG(Node g, Node s, Node p, Node o) {
        if (g == null || Quad.isDefaultGraph(g)) { //default graph case
            if (hasReadAccess(NodeFactory.createURI(DEFAULT_GRAPH_SECURITY_NAME))) {
                return base.findNG(g, s, p, o);
            }
        } else if (g.equals(Node.ANY)) {
            return Iter.filter(base.findNG(g, s, p, o), q -> hasReadAccess(q.getGraph()));
        } else {
            if (hasReadAccess(g)) {
                return base.findNG(g, s, p, o);
            }
        }
        throw new AccessDeniedException("User is not allowed to delete triples from graph " + g);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Node g, Node s, Node p, Node o) {
        Iterator<Quad> iter = find(g, s, p, o);
        boolean b = iter.hasNext();
        Iter.close(iter);
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Quad quad) {
        return contains(quad.getGraph(), quad.getSubject(), quad.getPredicate(), quad.getObject());
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        if (getBaseGraphNodes().stream().allMatch(this::hasDeleteAccess)) {
            base.clear();
        }
        throw new AccessDeniedException("User is not allowed to clear dataset.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return !contains(Node.ANY, Node.ANY, Node.ANY, Node.ANY);
    }

    @Override
    public Lock getLock() {
        return base.getLock();
    }

    @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        return base.getContext();
    }

    @Override
    public long size() {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        base.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsTransactions() {
        return base.supportsTransactions();
    }

    @Override
    public void begin(TxnType type) {
        base.begin();
    }

    @Override
    public void begin(ReadWrite readWrite) {
        base.begin(readWrite);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean promote(Promote mode) {
        return base.promote(mode);
    }

    @Override
    public void commit() {
        base.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void abort() {
        base.abort();
    }

    @Override
    public void end() {
        base.end();
    }

    @Override
    public ReadWrite transactionMode() {
        return base.transactionMode();
    }

    @Override
    public TxnType transactionType() {
        return base.transactionType();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInTransaction() {
        return base.isInTransaction();
    }
}
```

Code of SecuredDatasetAssembler

```
package com.vdanyliuk.jena.security;

import static org.apache.jena.permissions.AssemblerConstants.EVALUATOR_IMPL;
import static org.apache.jena.permissions.AssemblerConstants.URI;
import static org.apache.jena.sparql.util.graph.GraphUtils.exactlyOneProperty;
import static org.apache.jena.sparql.util.graph.GraphUtils.getStringValue;
import static org.apache.jena.tdb.assembler.VocabTDB.pLocation;
import static org.apache.jena.tdb.assembler.VocabTDB.pUnionDefaultGraph;

import org.apache.jena.assembler.Assembler;
import org.apache.jena.assembler.Mode;
import org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup;
import org.apache.jena.assembler.exceptions.AssemblerException;
import org.apache.jena.atlas.logging.Log;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Node;
import org.apache.jena.permissions.AssemblerConstants;
import org.apache.jena.permissions.SecurityEvaluator;
import org.apache.jena.query.Dataset;
import org.apache.jena.query.DatasetFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetGraph;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.AssemblerUtils;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.NodeValue;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.util.MappingRegistry;
import org.apache.jena.sys.JenaSystem;
import org.apache.jena.tdb.TDB;
import org.apache.jena.tdb.TDBFactory;
import org.apache.jena.tdb.assembler.DatasetAssemblerTDB;
import org.apache.jena.tdb.base.file.Location;

public class SecuredDatasetAssembler extends DatasetAssembler {
    private static boolean initialized;

    static {
        JenaSystem.init();
        init();
    }

    private static synchronized void init() {
        if (initialized)
            return;
        MappingRegistry.addPrefixMapping("sec", AssemblerConstants.URI);
        registerWith(Assembler.general);
        initialized = true;
    }

    /**
     * Register this assembler in the assembler group.
     *
     * @param group The assembler group to register with.
     */
    private static void registerWith(AssemblerGroup group) {
        if (group == null)
            group = Assembler.general;
        group.implementWith(ResourceFactory.createProperty(URI + "SecuredDataset"), new SecuredDatasetAssembler());
    }

    @Override
    public Dataset createDataset(Assembler a, Resource root, Mode mode) {
        return make(a, root);
    }

    private static Dataset make(Assembler a, Resource root) {
        if (!exactlyOneProperty(root, pLocation))
            throw new AssemblerException(root, "No location given");

        String dir = getStringValue(root, pLocation);
        Location loc = Location.create(dir);
        DatasetGraph dsg = TDBFactory.createDatasetGraph(loc);

        Resource evaluatorImpl = getUniqueResource(root, EVALUATOR_IMPL);
        if (evaluatorImpl == null) {
            throw new AssemblerException(root,
                    String.format("Property %s must be provided for %s", EVALUATOR_IMPL, root));
        }
        SecurityEvaluator securityEvaluator = getEvaluatorImpl(a, evaluatorImpl);

        dsg = new SecuredDatasetGraph(dsg, securityEvaluator);

        if (root.hasProperty(pUnionDefaultGraph)) {
            Node b = root.getProperty(pUnionDefaultGraph).getObject().asNode();
            NodeValue nv = NodeValue.makeNode(b);
            if (nv.isBoolean())
                dsg.getContext().set(TDB.symUnionDefaultGraph, nv.getBoolean());
            else
                Log.warn(DatasetAssemblerTDB.class, "Failed to recognize value for union graph setting (ignored): " + b);
        }

        AssemblerUtils.setContext(root, dsg.getContext());
        return DatasetFactory.wrap(dsg);
    }

    private static SecurityEvaluator getEvaluatorImpl(Assembler a, Resource evaluatorImpl) {
        Object obj = a.open(a, evaluatorImpl, Mode.ANY);
        if (obj instanceof SecurityEvaluator) {
            return (SecurityEvaluator) obj;
        }
        throw new AssemblerException(evaluatorImpl, String.format(
                "%s does not specify a SecurityEvaluator instance", evaluatorImpl));
    }

}
```

The last one is mostly copied from DatasetAssemblerTDB, and just wraps created dataset with an implementation described above.

Comment: While with latest Apache Fuseki 3.10 the security layer was [extended](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/data-access-control), I'm not sure whether this helps. I'd think that you can define something for a dataset such that it holds for each graph.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me. Was not aware of this. But unfortunately looks like such setup supports only predefined users. Jena SecurityEvaluator works just perfect for me as I want to have the ability to grant access based on information in the security graph. The problem is that whenever data is inserting into not existing graph Fuseki creates unsecured default instance.

Comment: There is no fundamental restriction on predefined users (it's behind an `AuthPolicy`) - what use case had you in mind?  The configuration files are fixed and the examples are for standalone usage, but the design allows for connection to local environment policies.

Comment: The use-case is the next: there can be newly created graphs and newly created users. There will be one graph with access info that will be used to decide if to grant permissions for a concrete graph to a concrete user.

Comment: Actually I'm ended up with another problem. How to apply SecurityEvaluator to a TDBDataset as this dataset takes no Model not Graph as argument?

Comment: you have to define it for every graph or model in the dataset I guess. @AndyS knows better. Or you directly ask for support on the [Jena mailing list](https://jena.apache.org/help_and_support/) and describe the whole use-case at once instead of follow-up questions here.

Comment: Security on TDB can be on services (update and query) or per-graph (query actions) as the code stands at the moment. If you want to integrate the model-level SecurityEvaluator then it'll need a general dataset and manage each model separately. Integrating into an environment where users are created (and removed?) isn't currently provided - we need more examples of what to integrate with, assuming there isn't a whole user management function added to Fuseki which probably won't help most people where centrally managed SSO is needed.

Comment: Fuseki supports Shiro security, and it can be perfectly integrated with any existing authentication technique, but I can't understand how to integrate it with graph-level authorization when no graphs nor users are predefined.

Comment: I have updated question.